# Update XML schema in infromatica mapping

Tags: informatica

I have created a mapping where I took the source as a XML schema. But now I need to update xml schema with existing schema in the same mapping. But main problem is that the code is deployed on production server, and there is no client to udpate the xml schema.

Can you please tell me the procedure to update the existing XML schema with new XML schema via using commands.

Appreciate your support !!

Comment: Thanks Marek for your response... But I can't redeploy the code as you know that re-deploy should be the part of release. But I can paste the new XSD file and have privilege to run the commands on production.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a dynamically mapping using XML transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921445/create-a-dynamically-mapping-using-xml-transformation)